how can we handle fixed width and fixed height, float or position: absolute or fixed in aura components in security review
.THIS .slds-docked-composer{
    float : right !important;
}
.THIS .messageInput {
    height : 380px !important;
    width : 320px !important;
}

How can we avoid using of fixed height and fixed width, float or position: absolute or fixed in aura component. because these are the vulnerable in security review.

Could you please elaborate & share the exact vulnerability reported in security review? It will help us solve your issue better.

Refer to this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_css_tips.htm

Tips for CSS in Components has three recommendations:

Components must be set to 100% width
Don’t remove HTML elements from the flow of the document
Child elements shouldn’t be styled to be larger than the root element

Your component must be responsive, therefore fixed sizes are prohibited. Instead, use lightning-layout to specify responsive widths, and even to align columns to a particular area (e.g. align a layout item to the right, similar to float).
The reason for these limitations are to prevent accidentally or intentionally breaking the user interface by not sharing space with other components that may be on the page. I recommend you read the entire document linked above for more information on each of these three rules and why they exist.
